# Should I trust Mathematica or numerous other sources on this Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, transformation, mathematica

Assume $a>0$

So [Mathematica claims](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=fourier%20transform%20e%5E%28-a%7Ct%7C%29)

$$F\{e^{-a|t|}\}(\omega) = \frac{a\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}}{a^2+\omega^2}$$

However, I've read about [another transform pair](http://uspas.fnal.gov/materials/11ODU/FourierTransformPairs.pdf) (page 3):

$$F\{e^{-a|t|}\}(\omega) = \frac{2a}{a^2+\omega^2}$$

They clearly are not equal, when you let $a=2$, mathematica claims the transform is $\frac{1.60}{4+\omega^2}$, and the other source claims it's $\frac{4}{4+\omega^2}$. Which one is right, and why do they differ?

Comment: In the mathematica documentation, you should look up "FourierParameters" which is the option whose default value differs from the assumption on page 3

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Different definitions

Note that Mathematica and your link use different definitions of the Fourier transform.

Mathematica uses (you can see this under "Details and Options" in the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FourierTransform.html)):
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{- \infty}^\infty f(t) e^{j \omega t} dt$$
and your link uses:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) e^{-j \omega t} dt$$
so the transforms differ by a factor of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}$ **and** that Mathematica does not have the negative sign in the exponent.

In this case we can see that the only difference is the factor $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}$:
$$\frac{a\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}}{a^2+\omega^2} \bigg/ {\frac{2a} {a^2+\omega^2}} = \frac{a\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}(a^2 + \omega^2)}{2a(a^2 + \omega^2)} = \frac{\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}}{2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}$$
so it works out.

Note that due to the fact of the missing minus sign in the exponent, we can get other differences as well, e.g. Mathematica says that the Fourier transform of $\operatorname{sign}(t)$ is
$$\frac{j \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }}}{\omega} = - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \underbrace{\frac{2}{j \omega}}_{:=A}$$
where $A$ is what your link says the transform is. The additional difference here is that we have a minus sign.

### But why?

The definition that Mathematica uses has an advantage in that the inverse Fourier transform looks very similar to the Fourier transform:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty F(\omega) e^{-j \omega t} d\omega.$$
It is not only Mathematica that uses this definition, it is commonly used.

### Getting Mathematica to do what you want

What you might want to do, to get the same behavior in Mathematica as in your link, is set FourierParameters to $\{1,-1\}$, so `FourierTransform[Exp[-a Abs[t]], t, \[Omega], FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]` returns
$$\frac{2 a}{a^2+\omega^2}$$
and `FourierTransform[Sign[t], t, \[Omega], FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]` returns
$$-\frac{2 i}{\omega}.$$
Note that `FourierParameters` can also be used with `InverseFourierTransform`. The details for what `FourierParameters` does can be found in the documentation for `FourierTransform`, under "Details and Options".

Comment: Additionally, if I remember right, the coefficient difference is due to a normalization when we treat the transform as a member of $B(L^1)$, the space of bounded linear operators on the integration space $L^1$.

Answer (score 3):

There are different definitions of the Fourier Transform. The confusion comes from Mathematica and your reference using different definitions for the Fourier Transform. They are equivalent up to a constant. Most people, and Mathematica use the definition: $$F[f](\omega)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{-ix\omega}dx.$$
Others use the definition 
$$F[f](\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{-ix\omega}dx.$$
The reason for the difference comes from the inverse transform. If we use the definition, the inverse transform is: $$F^{-1}[f](x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\omega)e^{ix\omega}d\omega.$$
The second definition yields an inverse transform of $$F^{-1}[f](\omega)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\omega)e^{ix\omega}d\omega.$$
So notice that both definitions have a total coefficient of $1/(2\pi)$. Different people have different preferences as to how do balance the coefficient between the transform and the inverse transform.

Comment: “They are all equivalent up to a constant” – actually not. There's another definition around, $F(f)(\nu) = \int_\mathbb{R}\!\mathrm{d}t\: f(t)\cdot e^{-2\pi i \nu t}$, whose inverse is simply $F^{-1}(f)(t) = \int_\mathbb{R}\!\mathrm{d}\nu\: f(\nu)\cdot e^{2\pi i \nu t}$. No multiplying factors at all, but a different notion of frequency!

Comment: You are right. I have seen this before, but didn't think about it. I changed my answer to apply only to these specific two definitions.

Comment: @leftaroundabout And even that one can be seen as equivalent if you do an appropriate change of variable (and redefinition of $f$). They all give roughly the same thing, but the interpretations vary.